# Nested Ruby List Generation

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, range, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to generate a list that looks like this:

```
list = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], ... [25, 25]]
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with something similar to [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html)?

**Update**: Looks like .zip wins

- .map time elapsed 1184.344 milliseconds
- .zip time elapsed 706.23 milliseconds

Test:

```
beginning_time = Time.now
(1..2500000).map { |i| [i,i] }
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"

beginning_time = Time.now
(1..2500000).zip 1..25
end_time = Time.now
puts "Time elapsed #{(end_time - beginning_time)*1000} milliseconds"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(1..25).map { |i| [i,i] }
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10], [11, 11], [12, 12], [13, 13], [14, 14], [15, 15], [16, 16], [17, 17], [18, 18], [19, 19], [20, 20], [21, 21], [22, 22], [23, 23], [24, 24], [25, 25]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(1..25).zip 1..25
#=> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Array.new(25){|i| [i+1, i+1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 2 hours late, and, just to be different...

```
[[*1..25], [*1..25]].transpose
# => [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], ...
```

...or...hehe...

```
([[*1..25]]*2).transpose
```